# Scrollbar on window resize for only one div in multi-div vertical layout

Tags: css, scrollbar, vertical-scrolling, window-resize

I've been on this for days and read every conceivable article on css, overflow, and layout.

I have a page with a banner (*position: absolute*), below which is a div containing two block divs. The second block div, in turn has another div containing text.

I would like the inner-most DIV display a scroll bar when the window is resized.

I've read the posting on ensuring height is set on all containing elements, I've set *overflow-y: auto* in all the right places.  Just doesn't work.

The containing DIV looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XraSL.png

I want the **green part** to scroll when the browser window is resized (y-direction only).

Scrollable DIVs in any design are so useful... but shouldn't be this hard.
Any and all help appreciated.

Danny

**MARKUP**

The markup is very simple:

```
<body>
    <div id="page-header" style='background:blue;'>page-header</div>
    <div id="page-content">
        <div id="configContent" style='height: inherit; background: steelblue;'>
            <h1 id='panTitle'>Panel Title</h1>
            <div id='panProbes' class='libPanel' style="background: maroon;">
                <p>panProbes</p>    
                <div id="probesCT1" class="configtable" style='background: red;'>
                    <p class='pTblTitle'>probesCT1</p>
                </div>
                <div id="probesCT2" class="configtable" style='background: grey;'>
                    <p>probesCT2</p>
                    <div id='pTbl' style='background: green;'>
                        <div class='pRow'>1st para in pTbl</div>
                        <div class='pRow'>some data</div>
                        <div class='pRow'>some data</div>
                        <div class='pRow'>some data</div>
                        <div class='pRow'>some data</div>
                        <div class='pRow'>some data</div>
                        <div class='pRow'>some data</div>
                        <div class='pRow'>some data</div>
                        <div class='pRow'>some more data</div>
                        <div class='pRow'>some more data</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

** STYLING **

Here's the CSS cut down to the core essence:

```
html, body {    
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1010px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#page-header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

#page-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 95px;
}

#configContent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    border-width: 3px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.libPanel { height: 100%; }

#probesCT1 { width: 150px; margin: 0 auto 0 30px; }
#probesCT2 { 
    width: 200px;
    /* height: 100%; */
    margin: 0 30px 50px 30px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#pTbl { overflow-y: auto; }
.pRow { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem u r facing? the code 
`#probesCT2 { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 60%; 
    margin: 0 30px 50px 30px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#pTbl { overflow-y: auto; height: 70%; }`

works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

For `overflow-y: auto` to work and make scroll bars, that `div` must have a specific height set. So [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/F339K/3/) (with your html above) I set it to `200px`, which was less space than necessary to display the content without a scroll bar, and thus shows a scroll bar. However, if set to `100%` [it does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/F339K/4/), because 1) you need to uncomment the height of the containing divs, and 2) your content in that div is less than needed to fill the height of the div, so no scroll bar shows up. With more content added, [you get a scroll bar](http://jsfiddle.net/F339K/7/).

What I think you really want is to insure you always have a scroll bar if needed, but even then, you need to make sure the div does not extend below the bottom of the page or you could still have problems with the scroll bar itself going off the page. [I've configured something](http://jsfiddle.net/F339K/27/) that is probably more what your intent is, but note that I had to use multiple nested `relative` or `absolute` elements to achieve the effect. I also had to guess on some height positioning for the top of elements to clear your titles.